# GCP Storage Bucket - Any option to change the storage class based on last updated time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, lifecycle, bucket

My requirement is to move the files to archive, once the (current time - last access time) is greater than a specific value. Is such an option possible?

I went through the documentation, but, did not see any storage class change option based on last accessed timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lifecycle on Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) to change the storage class based on temporal conditions.

Comment: I did not find any option that uses the last accessed timestamp, it is always based on creation time

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch the last accessed. It's not possible. The last read isn't a metadata in GCS. You need to build your own system for this use case.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation...Yes, what you said is correct

Answer (score 0):

Google's lifecycle has an option condition called "Days since custom time".
Presumably you could set the custom time whenever you access an object and this would work.

Comment: Have you tested it by yourself in fact ?

Comment: @sylvain - no I haven't